# Derive the Gauss-Legendre quadrature rule on [0,1] using 3 points.

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods

Below are my workings, Please comment if they are correct or where the mistakes are. Thanks :)

Given Legendre Polynomial $L_3(x)=5x^3-3x$,

the roots are $-\sqrt \frac{3}{5}$, $0$, $\sqrt \frac{3}{5}$

Let $t=Ax+B$.

$-1=A\cdot 0+B \implies B=-1$

$1=A\cdot 1+B \implies A+B=1 \implies A=2$

So, $t=2x-1 \implies x=\frac{t+1}{2}$

where $dx = (1/2) dt$

Let $t_0 = -\sqrt \frac{3}{5}$, $t_1 = 0$, $t_2 = \sqrt \frac{3}{5}$

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} f(\frac{t+1}{2}) dt$

Let $g(t) = f(\frac{t+1}{2})$,

Then, $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}g(t)dt$

By Gauss-Legendre Quadrature Rule,

$\int_{-1}^{1}g(t)dt \approx \sum_{i=0}^{2}\int_{-1}^{1}L_{2,i}(t)\cdot g(t_i)dt$

$L_{2,0}(t) = \frac{(t-t_1)(t-t_2)}{(t_0-t_1)(t_0-t_2)} = \frac{5}{6}(t^2-\sqrt {\frac{3}{5}}t)$

$L_{2,1}(t) = \frac{(t-t_0)(t-t_2)}{(t_1-t_0)(t_1-t_2)} = -\frac{5}{3}(t^2+1)$

$L_{2,2}(t) = \frac{(t-t_0)(t-t_1)}{(t_2-t_0)(t_2-t_1)} = \frac{5}{6}(t^2+\sqrt {\frac{3}{5}}t)$

$\int_{-1}^{1} L_{2,0}(t) dt = \frac{5}{9}$

$\int_{-1}^{1} L_{2,1}(t) dt = \frac{8}{9}$

$\int_{-1}^{1} L_{2,2}(t) dt = \frac{5}{9}$

Hence, $\int_{-1}^{1} g(t)dt \approx \frac{5}{9}g(t_0)+\frac{8}{9}g(t_1) + \frac{5}{9} g(t_2) = \frac{5}{9} f(\frac{t_0 +1}{2}) + \frac{8}{9} f(\frac{t_1 +1}{2}) + \frac{5}{9} f(\frac{t_2 +1}{2}) = \frac{5}{9} f(x_0) + \frac{8}{9} f(x_1) + \frac{5}{9} f(x_2)$

where $x_i = \frac{t_i + 1}{2}$ for $i=0,1,2$.

Therefore, $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}g(t)dt \approx \frac{5}{18}f(x_0) + \frac{4}{9} f(x_1) + \frac{5}{18} f(x_2)$

where the highest possible degree of precision is 5.

Comment: Surely the roots are $\pm\sqrt{3/5}$, right?

Comment: i made a mistake while typing it on latex, hold on let me edit it.

Comment: Yes, you used the right values later on: it's only the first two occurrences that are wrong.